# Atom design methodology for ion-input

Tags: angular, components, frontend, ionic4, ionic-native

I am trying to implement the atom design methodology inside ionic. My first step is to create the atoms and I decided to start with ion-input since it seems the hardest to me.

So my app-input html looks like this:

```
<ion-input 
  [accept]="accept"
  [autocapitalize]="autocapitalize"
  [autocomplete]="autocomplete"
  [autocorrect]="autocorrect"
  [autofocus]="autofocus"
  [clearInput]="clearInput"
  [clearOnEdit]="clearOnEdit"
  [color]="color"
  [disabled]="disabled"
  [inputmode]="inputmode"
  [max]="max"
  [min]="min"
  [mode]="mode"
  [multiple]="multiple"
  [name]="name"
  [pattern]="pattern"
  [placeholder]="placeholder"
  [readonly]="readonly"
  [required]="required"
  [size]="size"
  [spellcheck]="spellcheck"
  [step]="step"
  [type]="type"
  [value]="value"
  [(ngModel)]="ngModel"
  ></ion-input>
```

I've put in all properties that it supports. Then in the component I defined all `@Input`'s:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-input',
  templateUrl: './input.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./input.component.scss'],
})
export class InputComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() accept: string | undefined;
  @Input() autocapitalize: string;
  @Input() autocomplete: 'off' | 'on' = 'off';
  @Input() autocorrect: 'off' | 'on' = 'off';
  @Input() autofocus: boolean = false;
  @Input() clearInput: boolean = false;
  @Input() clearOnEdit: boolean | undefined;
  @Input() color: string | undefined;
  @Input() disabled: boolean = false;
  @Input() inputmode: 'decimal' | 'email' | 'none' | 'numeric' | 'search' | 'tel' | 'text' | 'url' | undefined;
  @Input() max: string | undefined;
  @Input() min: string | undefined;
  @Input() mode: 'ios' | 'md';
  @Input() multiple: boolean | undefined;
  @Input() name: string;
  @Input() pattern: string | undefined;
  @Input() placeholder: null | string | undefined;
  @Input() readonly: boolean = false;
  @Input() required: boolean = false;
  @Input() size: number | undefined;
  @Input() spellcheck: boolean = false;
  @Input() step: string | undefined;
  @Input() type: 'date' | 'email' | 'number' | 'password' | 'search' | 'tel' | 'text' | 'time' | 'url' = 'text';
  @Input() value: null | string | undefined = '';
  @Input() ngModel: any;
  @Input() inputId: string = '';

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {}

}
```

And I call it this way:

```
<app-input [(ngModel)]="item.value"></app-input>
```

So why does this give me this error?:

> ERROR Error: No value accessor for form control with unspecified name
>   attribute

Is this the right way to do it?

Comment: in form you should add name attribute along with ngModel otherwise use standalone pass name attribute too

Comment: Why? It works for `ion-input` without name attribute if I declae ngModel

Comment: if you are using inside form you will have to add name attribute along with ngModel